# Is there a powershell command for azure functions

Tags: azure-functions, azure-powershell

Is there a powershell for azure functions? In azure cli there are commands to manage azure function. but are there for powershell like get-azfunction...

Answer (score 0):

The PowerShell module for Functions is here, currently in preview: https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Az.Functions